# How Were the Scammers from North Korea able to Hack SWIFT CODES?

Tags: banking, scams, transaction, swift, money-laundering

**Sanctions-Hit North Korea Stole $13.5 Million From Cosmos Bank: Report**

North Korea was reportedly using cyberspace for undercover operations "to acquire funds through a variety of measures in order to circumvent the sanctions".

$13.5 million was withdrawn from Cosmos Bank in over 14,000 simultaneous ATM withdrawals in 28 countries.

> UNITED NATIONS: The United Nations has said that North Korea carried
>   out the $13.5 million cyber heist of Pune's Cosmos Bank using a
>   network across 28 countries by breaking its internal safety measures
>   last year as the country was starved for foreign funds due to UN
>   sanctions.

**How did they Hack the Server ?

Is the SWIFT NETWORK compromisable ?**

Comment: What is the source of that quote? I see no citation, no URL.

Comment: A report on this with lots of links from a variety of agencies saying how they think it happened: https://www.zdnet.com/article/how-hackers-managed-to-steal-13-5-million-in-cosmos-bank-heist/ When dedicated teams have the backing and protection of a government, and likely millions in budget, there is a lot they can accomplish. But no, in short, they mostly attacked a bank, installed a bunch of malware, and then used the stolen information to trigger unauthorized transactions.

Answer (score 4):

The SWIFT network was not compromised.

The hacker's attacked the gateway software installed by the Bank that did not have the right firewall and certificate configurations